# Node.cloneNode() inconsistent with DOM Spec

Tags: javascript, html, dom, clone

It is well documented (mainly on SO) that using `Node.cloneNode(true)` on an `<input type="text">` returns a new `<input>` node with the same text contents as the original one, but cloning a `<select>` (after a user has chosen) returns a new `<select>` without the user selection. This at first seems to not follow the spec, because according to [DOM 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-3A0ED0A4):

> **`cloneNode`**
>   Returns a duplicate of this node, i.e., serves as a generic copy constructor for nodes. The duplicate node has no parent (parentNode is null) and no user data. *User data associated to the imported node is not carried over.*

The answer to why this happens is somewhat spelled out later, but it is more clear in the [DOM 2 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-3A0ED0A4),

> **`cloneNode`**
>   Cloning an Element copies all attributes and their values, including those generated by the XML processor to represent defaulted attributes, *but this method does not copy any text it contains unless it is a deep clone, since the text is contained in a child Text node.*

I'm willing to accept this behavior given this wording, although I'd argue that an `<input>` doesn't contain a text node, because the `childNodes` property of an `<input>` will always be an empty `NodeList` regardless if it contains text (in the spec's wording, "has a text node").

At the least, I understand that which `<option>` a user selects is considered user data, so it makes sense that this is not cloned. In this case, this "user data" is contained in the `selected` property of the `<option>`.

However, when [trying the behavior with radio buttons and checkboxes](http://jsbin.com/hufuxubige/2/edit?html,js,output), the behavior in Chrome 38, FF 33, Safari 6.2,  completely defies the above definition. Cloning checked checkboxes or selected radio buttons maintains their checked state. This seems to be contrary to the spec, since this information is "user data," which (like the `<select>`) is contained in a property (in this instance `checked`).

Am I correct that this does not align with the specification? If not, is there elsewhere where this behavior is defined? And if it is, is there a use case that explains why `cloneNode()` is so inconsistent about how it clones the states of user input fields?

---

*Edit:* While testing this against my suite of browsers, I discovered that Opera 12.15 performs as one would like with `<select>` inputs. Namely, it retains user selection on clone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DOM Level 4 defines [cloning steps](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-dom-20140710/#concept-node-clone-ext) clearlier:

> [Specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-dom-20140710/#other-applicable-specifications) may define *cloning steps* for all or some
>   [nodes](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-dom-20140710/#concept-node). The algorithm is passed *copy*, *node*, *document*, and
>   optionally a *clone children flag*, as indicated in the [clone](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-dom-20140710/#concept-node-clone)
>   algorithm.
>
> To clone a *node*, optionally with a *document* and a *clone children
>   flag*, run these steps:
>
> 1. If *document* is not given, let *document* be *node*'s [node document](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-dom-20140710/#concept-node-document).
> 2. Let *copy* be a [node](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-dom-20140710/#concept-node) that implements the same interfaces as *node*.
> 3. If *copy* is a [document](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-dom-20140710/#concept-document), set its [node document](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-dom-20140710/#concept-node-document) and *document* to *copy*.
>      Otherwise, set *copy*'s [node document](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-dom-20140710/#concept-node-document) to *document*.
> 4. Copy the following from *node* to *copy*, depending on the type of *node*:
>
>    - [`Document`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-dom-20140710/#document)
>        Its [encoding](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-dom-20140710/#concept-document-encoding), [content type](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-dom-20140710/#concept-document-content-type), [URL](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-dom-20140710/#concept-document-url), its mode ([quirks mode](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-dom-20140710/#concept-document-quirks), [limited quirks mode](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-dom-20140710/#concept-document-limited-quirks), or [no-quirks
>        mode](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-dom-20140710/#concept-document-no-quirks)), and its type ([XML document](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-dom-20140710/#xml-document) or [HTML document](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-dom-20140710/#html-document)).
>    - [`DocumentType`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-dom-20140710/#documenttype)
>        Its [name](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-dom-20140710/#concept-doctype-name), [public ID](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-dom-20140710/#concept-doctype-publicid), and [system ID](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-dom-20140710/#concept-doctype-systemid).
>    - [`Element`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-dom-20140710/#element)
>        Its [namespace](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-dom-20140710/#concept-element-namespace), [namespace prefix](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-dom-20140710/#concept-element-namespace-prefix), [local name](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-dom-20140710/#concept-element-local-name), and its [attribute list](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-dom-20140710/#concept-element-attribute).
>    - [`Text`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-dom-20140710/#text)
>    - [`Comment`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-dom-20140710/#comment)
>        Its [data](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-dom-20140710/#concept-cd-data).
>    - [`ProcessingInstruction`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-dom-20140710/#processinginstruction)
>        Its [target](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-dom-20140710/#concept-pi-target) and [data](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-dom-20140710/#concept-cd-data).
>    - Any other node
>        —
> 5. Run any [cloning steps](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-dom-20140710/#concept-node-clone-ext) defined for *node* in [other applicable specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-dom-20140710/#other-applicable-specifications) and pass *copy*, *node*, *document* and the *clone
>      children flag* if set, as parameters.
> 6. If the *clone children flag* is set, [clone](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-dom-20140710/#concept-node-clone) all the [children](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-dom-20140710/#concept-tree-child) of *node* and append them to *copy*, with *document* as
>      specified and the *clone children flag* being set.
> 7. Return copy.
>
> The `cloneNode(deep)` method must return a [clone](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-dom-20140710/#concept-node-clone) of the [context
>   object](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-dom-20140710/#context-object), with the *clone children flag* set if *deep* is true.

Both `select` and `input` are `Element`s, so only their [namespace](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-dom-20140710/#concept-element-namespace), [namespace prefix](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-dom-20140710/#concept-element-namespace-prefix), [local name](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-dom-20140710/#concept-element-local-name), and its [attribute list](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-dom-20140710/#concept-element-attribute) should be copied in step 4.

However, in step 5, additional cloning steps may run.
Probably, those steps include copying `value` and `selected` properties in case of `input` elements.

Comment: I agree this makes it clearer, however "cloning steps defined for *node* in other applicable specifications" seems vague (and it doesn't appear to link anywhere). What other specs could apply here? Also, how does this (or does it) explain why on all browsers the states of checkboxes and radio buttons are cloned over (despite that state not being in the "namespace, namespace prefix, local name, or attribute list)?

Comment: Yes, it's vague. I only wanted to point that DOM L4 potentially allows this behavior.